# phpQuery behaving weird, changing HTML

Tags: google-plus-one, phpquery

I want to process a template with a Google plusone button in it through phpQuery and I run into the following problem:

```
require_once( "phpQuery.php" );
$p = phpQuery( "<g:plusone></g:plusone>" );
echo $p->html();
```

the expected output would be:

```
<g:plusone></g:plusone>
```

But instead the output of this is:

```
<plusone></plusone>
```

Which doesn't match up with what google is expecting, so the button doesn't work any more. How can I stop phpQuery from changing (fixing?) my code, or how can I work around this problem without changing the string from plusone to g:plusone once the processing is done? (that's a nasty workaround, plus, I run into more of these 'translation'-problems in phpQuery).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while including a google+ badge. I could force the code generator from google to generate code with a div container. I just had to tick the "html5 valid code" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking all over for solutions for this problem, to no avail. I found a horrible workaround. I'm sure this is NOT the most elegant way to do this, but at least it fixes the problem.

Instead of the tags:

```
<g:plusone>...</g:plusone>
```

use:

```
<g__0058__plusone>...</g__0058__plusone>
```

Then simply str_replace the result before you're outputting:

```
echo str_replace("__0058__",":",$doc->html());
```

Basically in a tag where you would normally put a colon (:) you put **0058** instead. It's a very non-elegant solution, I realise that, but at least it's a workaround to this old problem.